# Error en código java ciclo FOR

Tags: java, bucle-for

Hola tengo duda con mi for, si pongo los operadores "== 6" pasa que compila bien pero no muestra nada en consola solo me aparece el BUILD SUCCESS! sin oportunidad de meter los datos.

Si pongo "= 6" me sale error.

Si pongo "< 6" me da chance de meter datos y me da los 6 ciclos.

Y si pongo "<= 6" me da 7 ciclos. ¿!?

Por ultimo si pongo ">= 6" hace lo mismo que los "==".

```
 Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i == 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca algun numero para saber si es par o impar: ");

            var numero = lectura.nextLine();
            int numberparse = Integer.parseInt(numero);
            if (numberparse % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(numero + " es numero par. ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(numero + " es numero impar. ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber porque está pasando debes de saber como funciona el ciclo `for`:

```java
for(int i = valor inicial; i <= valor final; i = i + paso) {
    //código
}
```

El valor inicial, es de donde parte nuestro ciclo `for`, después del primer `;` i se compara con un valor final, este no tiene sentido que sea comparado con un `==`, ya que el ciclo avanzará mientras esa condición  se cumpla.

En el código anterior, se traduciría en que, `i` parte con un **valor inicial**, en segundo lugar, el `for` se ejecutará mientras la variable `i` sea menor o igual que el **valor final**, por último, el **paso** se refiere como cambiará la variable `i`, en cada iteración (ej, de dos en dos, en unidad, etc.)

---

Al poner `i==6`, el `for` nunca se toca ya que el calor inicial de `i` es 0.

Por lo mismo tendrías que poner tu código así:

```
    Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
    //el for se ejecuta mientras i sea menor que 6
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca algún numero para saber si es par o impar: ");

        String numero = lectura.nextLine(); // cambie de var a String
        int numberparse = Integer.parseInt(numero);
        if (numberparse % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(numero + " es numero par. ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(numero + " es numero impar. ");
        }
        //podrás ver en que iteración te encuentras
        System.out.println("Me encuentro en el ciclo " + (i+1));

    }
```

[Vídeo explicativo del funcionamiento del ciclo for en español](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywIVQBaPRYk)

Comment: Gracias! pense que en mi valor final podia poner algo asi como = o == como en los if para forzar a que fuera ese único numero, pero ahora entiendo que debe ser <= para agarrar ese numero, me falla mucho el for :'( ya lo he entendido mejor,y  gracias por el video me suscribo a ese canal, me gustó su humor lol.

Comment: El vídeo es genial, se aprende mucho mejor con humor, totalmente recomendado, :) si es que esta respuesta te ha ayudado, no olvides marcar el check (✔), que se encuentra al lado izquierdo de la respuesta ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tu ciclo for esta mal formulado…

```
for (int i = 0; i == 6; i++)
```

Recuerda que el ciclo for es:

```
for (int i = VALORINICIAL; i CONDICION VALORFINAL; i INCREMENTO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si pones i==6 es igual a false por eso no entra

Si pones "= 6" Te da error porque un signo = es de asignación

Si pongo "< 6" me da chance de meter datos y me da los 6 ciclos.

Este esta bien le estas diciendo mientras i sea menor a 6 entra en el ciclo

Y si pongo "<= 6" me da 7 ciclos. ¿!?

Le estas diciendo si i es menor o igual, la diferencia con el de arriba es que arriba solo le estas diciendo menor a 6(0 al 5) y en este menor o igual son 7 número (0 al 6)

Por ultimo si pongo ">= 6" hace lo mismo que los "==".

Le estas diciendo que si i es mayor o igual a 6 y si empiezas en 0 pues 0 no es mayor o igual a 6, si empiezas en 6 entraría entrando al for, pero ten cuidado si es un for “normal” sumando 1 a i nunca va a terminar